# Cisco ASA 8.4+ redirect multiple ports - best practice?

Tags: networking, cisco, configuration, cisco-asa, best-practices

I was wondering whether anyone could advice on best practices as to the best way to redirect multiple ports for single host in the internal network.

As I understand this you can only nat a single port per object.  This caused a bit of a litter around in a config as I have to specify individual objects for the same host (IP) to redirect individual ports.

It looks as follows:

```
object network ratatouille-4569
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service udp 4569 4569 
object network ratatouille-ssh
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp ssh ssh
```

Now this approach have few obvious problems (especially if you've more complex/more rules) eg. if you need to change that internal host's IP address, you've to do this for each object individually.

In this specific case, I have 7 ports to redirect to this specific host.

I'd appreciate any advice about best-practice as how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible. You need to either specify each of the mapped ports manually or just set up a regular static NAT for all the TCP / UDP ports:

```
object network ratatouille
 nat (inside,outside) static interface
```

Comment: Yeah but in this case you're using the whole IP for just one internal host.  In my case, I've a single IP but multiple internal host which I want to redirect ports to.

I was more hoping for some advice what's the best way to maintain that.  Any specific naming conventions you guys use or some other tricks?  Or just do as I did above and keep it going like this?

Answer (score 0):

... and control desired ports with ACL assigned to outside interface

`access-list ratatouille-port-control permit tcp any host ratatouille.inside.IP eq 22
access-list ratatouille-port-control permit tcp any host ratatouille.inside.IP eq 4569
access-list ratatouille-port-control permit tcp any host ratatouille.inside.IP eq 8080
access-group ratatouille-port-control outside in`

Comment: Please give a complete answer.  This appears to be a comment or follow-on to another question, but your answer can appear on its own so the meaning is unclear.